# how to cast all columns of dataframe to string

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a mixed type dataframe. 
I am reading this dataframe from hive table using 
`spark.sql('select a,b,c from table')` command.

Some columns are int , bigint , double and others are string. There are 32 columns in total.
Is there any way in pyspark to convert all columns in the data frame to string type ?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Just:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

table = spark.sql("table")

table.select([col(c).cast("string") for c in table.columns])
```

Comment: This method had performance advantage over withCcolumns when dealing with thounsands columns with version 2.1.0

Comment: @user7526416 How would you achieve the same if you wanted to do it on a Spark's `Dataframe`, say, df?

Comment: df = df.select([col(c).cast("string") for c in df.columns])

Answer (score 20):

Here's a one line solution in Scala :

```
df.select(df.columns.map(c => col(c).cast(StringType)) : _*)
```

Let's see an example here :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val data = Seq(
   Row(1, "a"),
   Row(5, "z")
)

val schema = StructType(
  List(
    StructField("num", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("letter", StringType, true)
 )
)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),
  schema
)

df.printSchema
//root
//|-- num: integer (nullable = true)
//|-- letter: string (nullable = true)

val newDf = df.select(df.columns.map(c => col(c).cast(StringType)) : _*)

newDf.printSchema
//root
//|-- num: string (nullable = true)
//|-- letter: string (nullable = true)
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

```py
for col in df_data.columns:
     df_data = df_data.withColumn(col, df_data[col].cast(StringType()))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

For Scala, spark version > 2.0

```
case class Row(id: Int, value: Double)

import spark.implicits._

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val r1 = Seq(Row(1, 1.0), Row(2, 2.0), Row(3, 3.0)).toDF()

r1.show
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|  1.0|
|  2|  2.0|
|  3|  3.0|
+---+-----+

val castedDF = r1.columns.foldLeft(r1)((current, c) => current.withColumn(c, col(c).cast("String")))

castedDF.printSchema
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = false)
 |-- value: string (nullable = false)
```

Answer (score -2):

you can cast single column as this

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
df = df.withColumn("id", F.col("new_id").cast(T.StringType()))
```

and just for all column to cast