# Pyspark writing data frame results into a text file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to write data frame results in to  a text file and i am getting below error ,i am not understanding what exactly wrong with the datatypes

Here are my  Dataframe results

[image]

I am using below code to write results into text file

```
User_cast.write.mode("overwrite").option("compression","bzip2").format("text").save("loc/path")
```

getting below error

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Text data source does not support double data type.;'
```

Comment: Perhaps if you execute `User_cast.printSchema()` problem will become clearer?

Comment: Thanks @mazaneicha ,i executed User_cast.printSchema() and schema was defined like below 
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- salary: double (nullable = true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is indeed the expected behaviour. You have two options to solve this. Either you cast all the types of your dataframe to `StringType` (e.g. using this answer [how to cast all columns of dataframe to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42080730/how-to-cast-all-columns-of-dataframe-to-string)) and concatenate them together (`text` datasource only supports one column), or your save as `csv`. Reconstructing your problem:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
colnames = [str(i+1) for i in range(11)]
df1 = spark._sc.parallelize([
  [it for it in range(11)], 
  [it for it in range(1,12)]]
).toDF((colnames))


df1.write.mode("overwrite").option("compression", "bzip2").format("text").save("./path")

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o67.save.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Text data source does not support bigint data type.;
```

I can, however, write to a CSV, by changing the format to `csv`, such as:

```
df1.write.mode("overwrite").option("compression", "bzip2").format("csv").save("./path")
```

Looking up the output (which will vary on your partitioning etc.)

```
! ls path
part-00000-7db004e7-7309-466c-ba7b-112127e286ae-c000.csv.bz2
part-00001-7db004e7-7309-466c-ba7b-112127e286ae-c000.csv.bz2
part-00003-7db004e7-7309-466c-ba7b-112127e286ae-c000.csv.bz2
_SUCCESS
```

Hope this helps!